# Zoom and resolution

Tags: html, css, zooming, responsive-design, screen-resolution

1. I have given heights and widths in percentages. And even the font sizes.
   Now on zoom in, the heights and widths of container do not change but font sizes change. It causes problem, as text comes out of containers on zoom in.
2. If I give height width in fix pixels, it works fine with zoom as containers and inner text are synchronized while zooming, but this way the site gets horizontal scrolls on different resolutions which is again undesired.

Is there a way to fix both these problems at a time?

[My page on JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/erigij/1/edit)

Comment: Is this a mobile site? I see you're using a table in the footer. It's bad practice to use a table for layout purposes. Tables should only be used to display tabular data.

Comment: You are right. Would you like to answer the question as well please. Even if i avoid that bad practice still i am unable to get solution for the problem

Comment: As I said, is it a mobile site? If so you should add a viewport tag. You could set it to be not user scalable in that tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

Percentages are relative to the parent element size. Extrapolating this relationship all the way up to `body` your window size isn't changing in size therefore the elements don't change in size. If you resize your window the elements will adjust size as the parent elements are changing dimensions.

Use `em` sizing if you want the elements to change size as this is set according to the default browser `font-size` (typically `16px`). As you zoom in and out the elements should adjust in size along with the fonts.

Ethan Marcotte wrote an excellent article for A List Apart describing how to achieve fluid layouts with `em`: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/